# Transparent caching solution

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, cache, transparent-proxy

I would like to in some cases make transparent caching for certain sites. Let's say that I have a static list of site from where I want to cache all downloads, ie: the client wants to download www.hotsite.com/afile.ext and the transparent proxy intersects the request, downloads the file, caches it, and the next time some client requests for that file it retrieves the file from the cache instead for downloading it again.
I don't care if the remote file changes in time, what options do I have?

Update 1: So far I've been using Varnish but it does not handles https and also I'm having problems with the cache manipulation (due to my inexperience)

Comment: You will not and should not be able to cache https.  At least not without installing your own certificate authority on client machines and decrypting all the traffic.  Which in most cases is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Squid to cache large files. It supports transparent proxy setups. I use it with WCCP (Web Cache Communication Protocol)

You can setup the ACL for squid to only cache certain websites. Few tweaks to maximum_object_size  and other things which are well documented on the internet will do the trick.

Comment: Can you please provide some links where i can read about?, it seems i don't know how to search about this topic